# How to select then click to an Element inside attribute tag with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to know How to click the ID "Uname" of input element which is inside the attribute "data-content" of another element.
I am using bootstrap for popover. when I click on  link it produce a popover but I want to click the element ID "Uname" inside data-content attribute

```js
$('a').on('click', function () {
        var content = $(this).data('content');
        var input = $(content);
        window.alert(input.attr('id'));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Username:"  data-content='<input id="Uname" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="You are Successfull!!!!" type="text"/><input id="btnEdit" type="button" value="Edit" />'>Click me!</a>
```

Comment: My apologies-- I have read your question several times and I still don't understand exactly what it is you are trying to do.  Can you try perhaps explaining what you want to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: An element in the html page has the attribute ` data-content` and the value of the attribute has an input tag with ID Uname. What jquery selector should be used to access that element is the question! Am i right @Benf

Comment: yes right @Keerthana Prabhakaran

Comment: I've posted the solution. Does that answer your question!?

Comment: not really, and how to get the value of an checkbox inside data-content attribut @Keerthana Prabhakara

Comment: I didn't see your answer, thanks for your help @Keerthana Prabhakara

Answer (score 0):

The popover `shown.bs.popover` event should be triggered! You'll get the pop over on clicking on the 'Click here' and then if you click on the input element popped, you can get the alert! 
Here is the snippet!

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({html:true});

$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
    $('#Uname').click(function(){
        alert($(this).data('content'));
    });

});
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Username:"  data-content='<input id="Uname" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="You are Successfull!!!!" type="text"/><input id="btnEdit" type="button" value="Edit" />'>Click me!</a>
```

Hope that helps!